# The set of even numbers less than 6

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The set of even numbers less than 6 is ?
E = {$0, 2 ,4$}
Or
E= {...., $-2 , 0 , 2 ,4$ } 
Which answer is correct?
The definition of the even number is any number can be written as $x = 2n$. 
Is $$n \in \mathbb Z$$
or
$$n\in \mathbb N ? $$

Comment: I guess it's a matter of definition, if negative numbers are also even/odd ... it could be that some people would consider only positive numbers. But on the other hand, nothing weird happens if you include the negative ones as well.

Comment: The correct answer depends on context, which you didn't specify.

Answer (score 6):

The even integers less than $6$ are $\ldots, -2, 0, 2, 4$.

The even whole numbers less than $6$ are $0,2,4$.

The even natural numbers less than $6$ are either $0,2,4$ or perhaps only $2,4$.

"Even number" is even more ambiguous than "even natural number".